# Does fwknop play nice with ufw?

Tags: iptables, ufw

The tutorial for `fwknop` says to block ports with an `iptables` script.

I don't want to use `iptables` since it's too confusing, I'd rather use `ufw`. But it seems like `ufw` does some complicated stuff, so I'm not sure if `fwknop` needs to be separately configured for this.

If I open/close my ports with `ufw`, will `fwknop` still work as if I had closed them with `iptables`?

Answer (score 0):

1) From fwknop documentation:

> The fwknop project supports four different firewalls: iptables,
>   firewalld, PF, and ipfw across Linux, OpenBSD, FreeBSD, and Mac OS X.
>   There is also support for custom scripts so that fwknop can be made to
>   support other infrastructure such as ipset or nftables.

So clearly, it officially supports 4 firewalls only. But there is room to add support for any other firewall manually. Do check the configuration file for more.

2) If you have UFW, then you also have iptables.

> The Uncomplicated Firewall (ufw) is a frontend for iptables and is
>   particularly well-suited for host-based firewalls. ufw provides a
>   framework for managing netfilter, as well as a command-line interface
>   for manipulating the firewall. ufw aims to provide an easy to use
>   interface for people unfamiliar with firewall concepts, while at the
>   same time simplifies complicated iptables commands to help an
>   adminstrator who knows what he or she is doing. ufw is an upstream for
>   other distributions and graphical frontends.

So if you block the ports by ufw it should work as though it were blocked by iptables itself. But to be honest, iptables is not that difficult to learn. To get you started, you only need to add the following rules to use fwknop.

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.1 on Tue Apr 23 15:11:27 2019
*nat :PREROUTING ACCEPT [129:17936] :INPUT ACCEPT [0:0] :OUTPUT ACCEPT [106:9180] :POSTROUTING ACCEPT [106:9180] COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Apr 23 15:11:27 2019
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.1 on Tue Apr 23 15:11:27 2019
*filter :INPUT ACCEPT [0:0] :FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0] :OUTPUT ACCEPT [91:9203]
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j LOG
-A INPUT -j DROP
-A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j LOG
-A FORWARD -j DROP COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Apr 23 15:11:27 2019
```

Just save the above text in any file. Then run the command:

> iptables-restore < filename

You will be good to go!

Answer (score 0):

According to [this tutorial on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/selfhosted/comments/bo04w3/locking_your_ssh_port_with_secure_port_knocking/), you can use `ufw` in your `/etc/fwknop/access.conf` like this:

> ```
> SOURCE                          ANY
>
> # Limit the Ports able to be opened
> OPEN_PORTS                      tcp/22
>
> # Keys from ~/.fwknoprc
> KEY_BASE64                      [...]
> HMAC_KEY_BASE64                 [...]
>
> CMD_CYCLE_OPEN                  /usr/sbin/ufw allow $PORT
> CMD_CYCLE_CLOSE                 /usr/sbin/ufw delete allow $PORT
>
> # Default cycle time Mandatory for CMD_CYCLE_OPEN/CLOSE
> CMD_CYCLE_TIMER                 180
> ```